# Limiting file size while writing using output stream in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to take data from console...when I'm entering data into file the file should take o 100kb of data and remaining data should be transferred to another file created dynamically ....

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  Your question is off-topic because you are asking for us to write your code for you.  StackOverflow is not a discussion, tutorial or code-writing site. The way this works is you are expected to attempt the solution and then ask for help when you run into a problem, explaining clearly what you have tried and what you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can keep track of size of string you have collected from console. Then you can create a new file when size exceeds your limit. To get the size of a string you can use `final byte[] utf8Bytes = yourString.getBytes("UTF-8");`